# Rails: nested association dosent set user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

hope youre having a good day.

So i have three models. `User`, `Project` and `TodoList`. a `User` hasMany `Project` and a project hasMany `TodoList`s, a todolist thus belongsTo a `User` and a `Project`.

here are the models

`User.rb`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :todo_lists
end
```

`Project.rb`

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant :user
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :members, class_name: 'ProjectUser'
  has_many :todo_lists

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

and `TodoList.rb`

```rb
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  has_rich_text :description

  has_many :todos
end
```

**My Problem**

when i try to create a todolist through associations, the user_id is not being set. for example when i do

```
u = some user

u.projects.new // => #<Project id: nil, user_id: 1, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

as you can see the user_id is set by rails which is expected behaviour. However when i try to create a new `TodoList` item through assosiactions, the user_id is not being set

```rb
u = some user

u.projects.first.todo_lists.new  #<TodoList id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: 5, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

as you can see, the `project_id` is being set successfully, but the `user_id` is not being set. is this expected from rails ? or i am doing something wrong? i can solve this throug setting the user manually like this

```rb
u = some user
p = u.projects.first
todo_list = p.todo_lists.new name: "complete tasks"
todo_list.user = u
todo_list.save
```

but i want to do it through associations, i hope my question makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `project.todo_lists.new`, the only detail `project` has is that its associated `todo_list` is being instantiated, and it sets the `project_id` in the newly instantiated object. `project` has no clue about how the `todo_list` is maintaining its `user_id`, hence, it does not set it.

That being set, you should not have both `user_id` and `project_id` in your `todo_list`. `todo_lists` table should instead only reference the `project_id`, and your model should be associated with the User model as,

```
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :user, through: :project
  has_rich_text :description

  has_many :todos
end
```

and your User model can reference the TodoLists as

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :todo_lists, through: :projects
end
```

By setting up your models as such, you are removing redundant data, your tables are better normalized, and there's less chance of having inconsistent data in your database (for example, a TodoList that belongs to a project for a different user then the once referenced in the list).

Comment: im curios how after implementing this, that a todolist will know what user it belongs to, could you please explain this?

Comment: the thing is that a project hasMany members, and any member can create a todolist thats why i need the user_id in my todolist table

Comment: It was not evident from your model as the Project `has_one` user. However if its the members that you need to be represented in the `TodoList` model, you should name them differently, such as `created_by` or `owner`